# Comma separated expression simplify

Tags: javascript, comma-operator

I'm trying to simplify code below

```
if (a ||
    node != r._start ||
    (start = n + r._startOff, a = true),
    a && node == r._end) {  .... }
```

Can someone help me to separate this if condition to simplify form? (without commas)?

Comment: Comma separated expressions evaluate to the last expression so `(start = n + r._startOff, a = true)` will always be `true`

Comment: Can you show how it will look after splitting?

Answer (score 0):

The code in the if condition will always run... this is the simplify version:

```
var doYourStuff = false;
if (a || node != r._start) {
    doYourStuff = true;
} else {
    start = n + r._startOff;
    a     = true;
    if (node == r._end) {
        doYourStuff = true;
    }
}

if (doYourStuff) {
    // ... do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Yeah I thought of something like that, but I gave up because of the lack of context. I'm not sure `a` has a great importance, it would simplify the algorithm.